# Как вызвать метод в objective-c с одним аргументом?

Tags: objective-c, методы

Все мы с вами знаем, что в Objective-c есть два способа вызова функции:

1. Посылка сообщения `[obj meth];`
2. Вызов метода `obj.meth;`

Мне шибко хочется научиться вызывать метод с одним аргументом вторым способом.
Если первым способом с одним аргументом `[obj meth:arg];`, то как будет выглядеть второй способ? 
Экспериментально установлено, что джавный трюк

`obj.meth(arg);`

в objective-c не работает.

Для примера, я на генерировал простой код:

```
#import "Cocoa/Cocoa.h"

@interface QNObject: NSObject
{
int num;
}
@end

@implementation QNObject

- (int) num:(int)x //метод принимает int на вход
 {
  return 5;
  }
 @end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; - НЕ НУЖНО    В ВЫСОКИХ ВЕРСИЯХ XCODE

 QNObject *o = [[QNObject alloc] init];
 NSLog(@"%d", [o num:9]); //ПОСЫЛАНИЕ СООБЩЕНИЯ. РАБОТАЕТ НОРМАЛЬНО
 NSLog(@"%d", o.num(5)); // ВЫЗОВ МЕТОДА. ВЫДАЕТ ОШИБКУ

 //   [o release]; - НЕ НУЖНО В ВЫСОКИХ ВЕРСИЯХ XCODE
//  [pool release]; - НЕ НУЖНО В ВЫСОКИХ ВЕРСИЯХ XCODE

return 0;
}
```

Как его переписать, чтобы в пятой строчке с конца не было ошибки?

Comment: В objective c вызов методов происходит с помощью сообщения; Если вы хотите вызвать как функцию попробуйте разобраться с блоками. Здесь можно почитать подробнее https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C;

Comment: C параметром не хочет вызвать через точку: NSLog(@"%d", [o num:(5)]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попытаюсь разъяснить ситуацию.

Когда вы объявляете `@property`, компилятор для вас генерирует два метода - геттер и сеттер. Выглядит это примерно так

```
@property NSString *myString;

- (NSString *)myString; // сгенерированный геттер
- (void)setMyString:(NSString*)aString; // сгенерированный сеттер
```

потом вы можете обращаться к этой проперти используя либо square bracket notation

```
NSString *myNewString = [self myString]; //getter
[self setMyString:myNewString];  // setter
```

либо используя dot notation

```
NSString *myNewString = self.myString; //getter
self.myString = myNewString; //setter
```

То есть, когда я пишу `self.myString = myNewString` на самом деле компилятор знает, что ему надо все это преобразовать и вызвать `setMyString:`. Сайд эффектом этого является ситуация при которой я могу вызвать любой метод используя дот нотейшн, если такой метод существует (не обязательно является сгенерированным для property).

Соответственно то, что вы пытаетесь сделать невозможно, поскольку в xcode такого механизма нет, и что во что преобразовать, когда дот нотейшн ведет себя и как геттер и как сеттер одновременно он не знает.

### UPDATE

Попробую привести больше примеров.

Если я написал `self.someMethod`, xcode будет искать метод с именем someMethod, который возвращает не void. Если найдет, то все нормально.

Если я написал `self.someMethod =` (с равно в конце), xcode будет искать метод `setSomeMethod`, который принимает один параметр. Опять же, если найдет, то все будет работать.

Это все, что умеет делать xcode, когда встречает дот нотейшн. Соответственно ваша задумка, где и параметр и что то вернуть, xcode'у не известна.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, но остается не понятным следующее: 
1. Во первых я @property не генерировал в коде. 


При этом, 
`- (int) num //метод ничего не принимает на вход
 {
  return 5;
  }
` 
...

Comment: `NSLog(@"%d", [o num]); //ПОСЫЛАНИЕ СООБЩЕНИЯ. РАБОТАЕТ НОРМАЛЬНО
 NSLog(@"%d", o.num); // ВЫЗОВ МЕТОДА работает 
`

Comment: То есть я хочу сказать, что ничего переписав метод так, что он ничего не получает на вход, метод работает и c dot notation и с bracket notation равно хорошо.  Почему?

Comment: вы одно предложение в ответе видимо упустили. про сайд эффект

Comment: а почему сайд эффект есть когда есть аргумент передающийся в метод, а когда аргумент не передается в метод, сайд эффекта нету?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Всё очень интересно, спасибо вам. Хорошо пояснили, просто я нифига не могу разобраться. Вы пишите,"  `self.someMethod =` (с равно в конце), xcode будет искать метод setSomeMethod, который принимает один параметр. Опять же, если найдет, то все будет работать. " - а я уже пробовал, и по ощущениям даже один аргумент без проперти синтезис не принимает. Принимает только "геттер" без аргумента. А можете совсем пустяк прояснить?
myString;
setMyString
Почему икскод генерирует сеттер с заглавной буквой в начале названия метода? 
А так спасибо, почти всё разъяснили.

Comment: насчет setMyString  - xcode так работает, дефолтное имя для сеттера: название проперти со словом set вначале и первое слово с заглавной буквы